# How do create a Sharepoint 'Mash up' combining Document Library and Project Tasks?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create a custom sharepoint site where I can use the 'Project Tasks' Template but additionally, allow users to attach documents to each task ah-la the Document Library template.  How do I do this? do I need to use Sharepoint Designer?

Answer (score 2):

It is enabled by default. In your Project Tasks list, click New. In addition to the fields (Title, Priority, Task Status, etc), there should be an Attach File button on the toolbar. The Attach File button will present you with a screen similar to the Upload Document screen of a Document Library.

Comment: Rich is right, and also, the concept of attachments are a SharePoint List thing, in Document Libraries you only have one file per item and this file is the item itself.